# Trades end point not working

Tags: horizon

Following url has stopped working
https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/order_book/trades?selling_asset_type=native&buying_asset_type=credit_alphanum4&buying_asset_code=FOO&buying_asset_issuer=GBAUUA74H4XOQYRSOW2RZUA4QL5PB37U3JS5NE3RTB2ELJVMIF5RLMAG&limit=20&order=desc

It used to work earlier, Any changes?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your [issuer](https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GBAUUA74H4XOQYRSOW2RZUA4QL5PB37U3JS5NE3RTB2ELJVMIF5RLMAG) doesn't exist on testnet, the endpoint works well

Answer (score 1):

That endpoint was renamed in 2017. `/order_book/trades` became `/trades`.

Check it out: https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/trades?selling_asset_type=native&buying_asset_type=credit_alphanum4&buying_asset_code=FOO&buying_asset_issuer=GBAUUA74H4XOQYRSOW2RZUA4QL5PB37U3JS5NE3RTB2ELJVMIF5RLMAG&limit=20&order=desc